# Artifactory can not parse Helm index.yaml

Tags: artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use Artifactory as a front for our Helm Charts. I have the following set up:

- helm-remote-stable : stable community Helm Charts
- helm-local-stable : stable company Helm Charts
- helm-stable: virtual repo with both of the above as upstreams

What's supposed to be happening is that the `helm-stable` virtual repo manages merging the two upstream index.yaml files.

However, I am getting the following exception in the logs:

```
2018-03-20 18:58:04,483 [art-exec-276943] [ERROR] (o.a.a.h.r.m.HelmVirtualMerger:194) - Couldn't read index file in remote repository helm-remote-stable : (was com.github.zafarkhaja.semver.UnexpectedCharacterException) (through reference chain: org.jfrog.repomd.helm.model.HelmIndexYamlMetadata["entries"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["grafana"]->java.util.TreeSet[6])
```

It looks like Artifactory is trying to enforce semver through some library and it's not parsing the community index.yaml file. This breaks the entire feature of the product.

Here's what's breaking from the community index.yaml:

```
- created: 2018-01-28T21:04:13.090211594Z
  description: The leading tool for querying and visualizing time series and metrics.
  digest: 6c25c79e16df4c31637d3f8b1b379bb4c0a34157fa5b817f4c518ef50d43911b
  engine: gotpl
  home: https://grafana.net
  icon: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grafana/grafana/master/public/img/logo_transparent_400x.png
  maintainers:
  - email: zanhsieh@gmail.com
    name: Ming Hsieh
  name: grafana
  sources:
  - https://github.com/grafana/grafana
  urls:
  - https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/grafana-0.6.tgz
  version: "0.6"
```

Please note the `version: "0.6"` which borking the entire thing.

Any idea on how to get around this? I am using the Artifactory cloud offering.

Comment: Have no idea on Artifactory, but Grafana Helm chart current version is 0.8.3. Check here: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/grafana/Chart.yaml

Comment: @MingXie You're correct that 0.6 is super old, but I'm not even trying to use the grafana chart. The problem is that Artifactory can't seem to parse the index.yaml file because of that version of the package.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in Artifactory version 5.9.0. 
You can find more details here: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15668

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the version of `grafana` chart from 0.6 to 0.6.0 and pushing it to `helm-local-stable`.